# script timed out before returning headers cgi

Tags: python, apache, cgi

i run a cgi script on an apache server (xampp). The script basically runs in an infinte loop. After like 3 minutes i get the error message "script timed out before returning headers". I've searched through the internet and found stuff like:

- change `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` to 0 -> didn't work
- `set_time_limit(0)` -> didn't work
- `socket.setdefaulttimeout(0)` -> didn't work

I think the error is caused because my script never returns anything to the website, but that's just like it's intended. Basically the script should be started through a website and run until i tell it to stop (it's done with the script constantly checking for a file).

One solution i thought about was a script that restarts my script if it's terminated. But a far more elegant solution would be that the script runs without being terminated by the server.

I hope everything is explained well and somebody can help me because i'm stuck with this problem for far too long and it's starting to annoy me.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try:

- Return a proper HTML header
- Print a dot `.` every few seconds, just to keep the connection alive
- disable mod_deflate in your Apache server to prevent HTTP compression
- add `SetEnv no-gzip` to your `.htaccess` file

Comment: I tried printing a dot every few seconds but i get the same output. What do you exactly mean by "return a proper html header"? In my script the first things i do are printing the content-type and the basic framework of html. Then the infinte loop follows, but the page never gets drawn because the infinte loop is never exited.

Comment: @SchimmelJoghurt: thanks for the clarification! didn't know that you are actually doing it, I added another idea which helped me in a similar case.

Comment: thanks for your help, but even after i disabled mod_deflate i got the error and my script was terminated.

Comment: Hi @SchimmelJoghurt: I just checked my own server, I added `SetEnv no-gzip`
to the `.htaccess` file in the cgi folder, perhaps this does the trick.